# Why doesn't projects/12 show all fields for that project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** The id does not matter, it is same in all cases.

I am only seeing the name field, not description, hours, etc even though these aren't null.

I have declared all standard routes through resources (with default format json), not individually.

I have even tried creating a projects/show.json.jbuilder file:

```
json.name @project.name
json.description @project.description
json.hours @project.hours
json.ownername @project.ownername
```

My projects/show method:

```
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
render :json => @project
```

**FIRST EDIT:**
I added logger.debug right before defining @project in my show method.

Now in my command prompt window for the local server, I am seeing:

```
Started GET "/projects/12" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-25 16:36:45 -0500
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by ProjectsController#show as HTML
Parameters: {"id"=>"12"}
Project Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "projects".* FROM "projects"  WHERE   "projects"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 12]]
#<Project:0x007f95477e72f8>
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id"   = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 51]]
Completed 200 OK in 42ms (Views: 15.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.9ms)
```

I am wondering why I am seeing the "User Load" part, since my Project model does not belong to a User object or have any relationship with it (though in the past it may have had before that relationship was removed). Also, I don't think I saw

```
#<Project:0x007f95477e72f8>
```

earlier.

Comment: Show what you **are** getting, and also add `logger.debug @project.to_json` above your `render` call above, and show the result of that from your log files.

Comment: smathy, please see the new information you asked for after the bolded FIRST EDIT in my original post.

Comment: I am basically seeing this for all projects' ids.

Comment: You didn't give the `.to_json` that I asked for :)  But great that you solved your issue, still makes no sense why your previous code would send JSON with just the name if the issue was that you weren't even asking for JSON, but anyway, great that you fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem this way.

Basically, projects/12.json currently works and not projects/12. Since I am more interested in obtaining the data client side, it is ok for me. I would need a projects/show.html.erb page that calls all the project data through view helper methods, for the HTML to work.

```
def show
@project = Project.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json 
 end
end
```

projects/12.json works because I have a projects/show.json.jbuilder file (as I shared in my original question post):

```
json.name @project.name
json.description @project.description
json.hours @project.hours
json.ownername @project.ownername
```